# Automated way to get an exe file to automatically run every three days in Windows 7 Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7, automation

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate. Let `abc.exe` be a file. Is it possible to automatically run `abc.exe` every three days? I am finding a 3rd-party program that can do this job.

Suppose that `abc.exe` was automatically run on 2016.1.3. morning. Suppose that I turned off the computer on `2016.1.3` afternoon, and did not use computer from 1.3 afternoon ~ 1.10 morning. Suppose that I turn on my computer on 2016.1.10, then `abc.exe` should run, though number 10 is not a multiple of 3. Because `abc.exe` was not automatically run for more than 3 days.

Comment: use the Windows Task scheduler to do this.

Comment: Could you please let me know correct trigger settings ? I only see 1day, 1 week, 1 month., THank you

Comment: In windows xp, you choose Perform this task: Daily then next and then again you have option Perform this task: and then you choose Every X days. I'm currently on xp but I'm sure 7 has this option too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is there an automated way run a program run every three days?

You get addition scheduling options if you use `Create Task` instead of `Create Basic Task`.

[image]

Set the schedule to `Daily` and set `Recur every` to `3`.

[image]

[image]

You may also want to look at the `Conditions` tab settings if you want to wake your computer to perform the task.

[image]